# vscode remote-ssh： the remote host's architecture is not support

Tags: vscode-remote

1.When attempting to remotely connect to Ubuntu using VSCode, I encountered an error that resulted in a popup window:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLnby.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvwC8.png)
For reference, my Ubuntu version can be found here:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8lsd.png)

2.I have verified that SSH and other related services have been successfully installed on Ubuntu, and that my version of Ubuntu is in accordance with VSCode's documentation. I have also confirmed that SSH services are functioning properly:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/HupDl.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucZXe.png)
My objective is to enable remote connectivity from VSCode to Ubuntu on my local machine using SSH.

Answer (score 0):

vscode remote unsupported architecture i686, Node no longer supports 32-bit linux. (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/1529)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).